# Is a 2W resistor sufficient to dissipate 0.6W of power?

Tags: power, resistors, watts

I'm looking at reducing the power of a 24V 0.1A fan by half. I've calculated that I need a 240 ohm resistor for this purpose. But I also need to choose the wattage.

I'm using the following website for my calculations:

https://www.blackfiveservices.co.uk/fanspeedcalc.php?Voltage=24&Current=0.1&Target=12

It summarizes:

> Power dissipated by resistor:  12V * 0.05A  =  0.6W

I've read that when choosing a resistor I should double the required wattage on the part.

Is a 2W resistor sufficient?

I'm trying to do this as inexpensively as possible as high watt resistors are expensive.

Comment: You can use series / parallel combinations of 1/4 W resistors as well. Then you'd have the option of going for 1 W, 1.5 W, etc. as required.

Comment: Fans are not resistive loads : you can't assume it takes 0.05A at 12V (you might want to measure it). That affects both the value and power rating of your resistor.

Comment: I think, rather than "can this resistor survive wasting a bunch of power and generating heat", perhaps you should be asking "how do I reduce a fan's power using PWM, which is both common and efficient"?

Comment: It's also worth noting that - depending on a lot of things, including the resistor's derating curve, expected ambient temperature, airflow, heatsink contact and thermal resistance - if your resistor is in the air flow path of the fan, you might get away with a smaller resistor. But resistors are so cheap that it's generally a better expenditure of engineering time to simply over-spec the resistor.

Comment: *I've read that when choosing a resistor I should double the required wattage on the part.* So you're saying that when a manufacturer states that a resistor can dissipate 1 W, we can only use it up to 0.5 W? In 35 years of dealing with electronics, I've never heard that one before. Because it is **nonsense**. If you want to have some margin, then yes, take a higher rated resistor. But always doubling the figure is silly. Next time: ask yourself **why** that would be needed.

Comment: 10W resistors are a buck or two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 2W will be cooler, because it's bigger, so has a larger thermal exchange surface with air.

If you don't have a 2W 240 ohm resistor in stock you can use four 1kOhm 0.25W resistors in parallel. If you put them in the airflow of the fan they should stay well below finger-burning  temperature.

Answer (score 0):

For things less than 5W, I typically double the wattage of what I calculate. 1W will work, but I do this because the resistor won't get as hot if it's a 2W compared to a 1W. Which means it's more likely to last longer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok.  A good rule of thumb (and a requirement in many companies) is that electronic components not be operated at greater than 50% of their ratings.  Obviously this cannot be held true in every situation, but in general -

Transistors - 50% of Vce (continuous)
Transistors - 50% of rated continuous collector current
Diodes - 50% of continuous or average forward current
Capacitors - 50% or rated voltage
Everything - 50% or rated continuous power dissipation

etc.